# How to use libraries in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp, asdf, quicklisp

I'm a beginner in Common Lisp and I want to use a library.

I can't find a single one simple example of loading / requiring / using a module.
I've installed cl-ppcre like this :

```
$ sbcl --non-interactive --eval '(ql:quickload "cl-ppcre")'
To load "cl-ppcre":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    cl-ppcre
; Loading "cl-ppcre"
..
```

But I don't know how to actually use it.
I've tried the following and a dozen other thing and not one works.

```
$ sbcl --noinform --non-interactive --eval '(progn (require "cl-ppcre") (cl-ppcre:split "\s+" "1 2 3"))'
Unhandled SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-PACKAGE-ERROR in thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING
                                                          {1004DB8073}>:
  Package CL-PPCRE does not exist.

    Stream: #<dynamic-extent STRING-INPUT-STREAM (unavailable) from "(progn (...">

Backtrace for: #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1004DB8073}>
0: (SB-DEBUG::DEBUGGER-DISABLED-HOOK #<SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-PACKAGE-ERROR "Package ~A does not exist." {1003640A83}> #<unused argument> :QUIT T)
1: (SB-DEBUG::RUN-HOOK *INVOKE-DEBUGGER-HOOK* #<SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-PACKAGE-ERROR "Package ~A does not exist." {1003640A83}>)
2: (INVOKE-DEBUGGER #<SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-PACKAGE-ERROR "Package ~A does not exist." {1003640A83}>)
3: (ERROR #<SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-PACKAGE-ERROR "Package ~A does not exist." {1003640A83}>)
```

**So how can I make it work ?**

**EDIT 1:**
I didn't precised that my problem with using libraries is as much a in scripts as in the terminal. It was implicit to me. This is because of my experience in Perl, in which everything you can do with a file, you can do at the command line, including using libraries.

**EDIT 2:**
Here is my working solution. As it turned out, there were 2 things were wrong. My problem required to :

1. using multiple `--eval`

Just like Svante and ignis volens said.

2. `(load "~/.quicklisp/setup.lisp")`

Which I was alrady explained here :

[Confused about ``ql:quickload`` and executable scripts in SBCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858237/confused-about-qlquickload-and-executable-scripts-in-sbcl)

This is the **terminal solution :**

```
sbcl --non-interactive --eval '(load "~/.quicklisp/setup.lisp")' --eval '(require :cl-ppcre)' --eval '(princ (cl-ppcre:split "\\s+" "1  2 3"))'
```

With the caveat that a bunch of warnings are outputed on stderr, like this one, and I don't know why that is.

```
WARNING: redefining QL-SETUP:QMERGE in DEFUN
```

And this is the **script solution :**

```
#!/usr/bin/sbcl --script

(load "~/.quicklisp/setup.lisp")
(require :cl-ppcre)

(princ (cl-ppcre:split "\\s+" "1    2 3"))
(terpri)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an instance of a common problem people have with CL.

The way CL (and other Lisps) work is in three phases (in fact more than three, but three is enough):

1. a sequence of characters is read to turn it into a form;
2. various magic happens to that form;
3. the result of stage 2 is evaluated, and perhaps the results printed.

Typically this process is iterated to process, say, a file, or a stream of input.

The important thing is that (1), (2), and (3) happen *in sequence*: (1) is complete before (2) begins, and both (1) and (2) are complete before (3) begins.

What that means is that (1) must be possible before anything that happens in (2) or (3) have happened.

So consider this form:

```
(progn 
  (ql:quickload "cl-ppcre")
  (cl-ppcre:split "\s+" "1 2 3"))
```

(This is pretty much one of the forms you are trying to evaluate.)

So the question is: what does it take for (1) to happen?  Well, it takes two things:

- the `QL` package (which is essentially a namespace: see below for more on what 'package' means in CL) must exist to read `ql:quickload`;
- the `CL-PPCRE` package must exist to read `cl-ppcre:split`.

And now you see the problem: `(ql:quickload "cl-ppcre")` *creates* the `CL-PPCRE` package, and this does not take place until (3).  That means that this form can't be read.

You can get around this, in desperation, with various heroic tricks.  However you don't actually need to: you can do something else, which (almost: see below) works:

```
(ql:quickload "cl-ppcre")
(cl-ppcre:split "\s+" "1 2 3")
```

And this is (almost) fine, because it's not one form: it's two.  So (1)-(3) work fine for the first form, and *then* (1)-(3) work fine for the second form.

So the answer is not to try and bundle everything into a single form.  Either put things in a file (probably the  best way) or if you really want to run things as command line arguments, you need to arrange that the forms are separate, with, for instance, multiple `--eval` options.

---

Above I said that the second, multiple-form, version *almost* works.  And it does only almost work.  The reason for this is file compilation.  Let's assume I have a file whose contents are:

```
(ql:quickload "cl-ppcre")
(cl-ppcre:scan ...)
...
```

Well, what does the compiler do when it compiles that file?  It reads it, form by form, but in general it *doesn't* actually execute code (there are exceptions): it arranges for that code to be executed when the file is loaded.  So the compiler will not load CL-PPCRE: it will arrange life so that when the file is *loaded* CL-PPCRE will be loaded.  And now we have a version of the same problem: the second form can't be read by the compiler because the `CL-PPCRE` package does not yet exist.

Well, there is a solution to that: you can tell the compiler that it must, in fact, execute some code at compile-time:

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (ql:quickload "cl-ppcre"))
(cl-ppcre:scan ...)
...
```

And now the compiler knows, thanks to the `eval-when` form, that it must call `ql:quickload`.  And it will do so, and so the `CL-PPCRE` package will be defined at compile time, and all will be well.

---

### A note on packages in CL

The term 'package' in CL has a meaning which is unfortunately not the same as it is in many other languages: that's because of history and can't now be changed.

In common usage, a package is 'some chunk of code which you can perhaps install and which perhaps has dependencies on other packages (chunks of code), all of which might be looked after by a package manager of some kind.  You might install Python as a package on your Ubuntu box, or you might use the `conda` package manager to manage scientific Python packages (including Python itself).

In CL a package is essentially a *namespace*.  If I type 'foo:bar' then this is referring to the symbol named `BAR` available in the package one of whose names or nicknames is `FOO`.  Further this is an 'external' symbol, which means it's intended to be public in some way.  Packages are real objects in CL and can be reasoned about by programs.  There is always a notion of a current package, and that package defines what names are available without requiring package prefixes both by directly containing some names and also having a search ('use') list of other packages.  There is a lot to packages in CL: far more than I can mention here.

What commonly might be referred to as packages are probably best referred to as 'libraries' in CL: they're chunks of code which you can install and which may have dependencies in their own right.  Alternatively they are often referred to as 'systems' as they are often defined using a 'system definition' tool.  'Library' is probably the better term: 'system' is again a historical oddity which can't really be changed now.

Comment: Thanks man, for taking the time to explain this. This is not sufficient for making me understand but it is enough so that I can begin to ask the right questions, and learn what is it that I don't know yet.

Comment: @WhiteMist: I've added a note on packages in CL which I think is a generally very confusing thing for newcomers and which term I'd previously just used without explanation, which was bad.

Answer (score 2):

Running programs from bash parameters as source is not the simplest way to start.  The problem is the order of compilation, loading, and executing.  Roughly, the parts you enter on the command line are first compiled, then loaded, but it would need to load the library first before it can compile the rest.  Thre might be ways around this, e. g. with multiple -e parameters, but I don't think that this is a useful exercise for a beginner.

If you just want to try things out from a command line, start SBCL without parameters, which will give you a REPL prompt.  That's a command line which accepts Lisp code.  It looks like `*` in vanilla SBCL.

```sh
[user@home]> sbcl
This is SBCL …
*
```

At that prompt, load your library:

```lisp
* (ql:quickload "cl-ppcre")
To load "cl-ppcre":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    cl-ppcre
; Loading "cl-ppcre"
[package cl-ppcre]................................
..........................
("cl-ppcre")
*
```

Then use it:

```lisp
* (cl-ppcre:split "\s+" "1 2 3")
("1 2 3")
*
```

Then you can quit the REPL:

```lisp
* (quit)
[user@home]>
```

For serious work, use files.

Answer (score 2):

**Packages**

Definitions

- a library or application is called a **system**.
- packages are namespaces for symbols
- symbols are named objects which often reside in a package

FOO::BAR denotes the symbol named BAR in the package FOO

FOO:BAR denotes the exported symbol named BAR in the package FOO

BAR denotes the symbol BAR in the current package

**To read a symbol with a specific package, that package needs to exist**

Example:

In LispWorks there is a package called CAPI -> we can find it.

```
CL-USER 44 > (find-package "CAPI")
#<The CAPI package, 5109/8192 internal, 880/1024 external>

CL-USER 45 > (read-from-string "CAPI::BAR")
CAPI::BAR
9
```

above creates a symbol named BAR in the existing package CAPI.

But there is no package called FOO. We can't find it:

```
CL-USER 46 > (find-package "FOO")
NIL
```

Now reading a symbol which is in package FOO is an error, since the package does not exist:

```
CL-USER 47 > (read-from-string "FOO::BAR")

Error: Reader cannot find package FOO.
  1 (continue) Create the FOO package.
  2 Use another package instead of FOO.
  3 Try finding package FOO again.
  4 (abort) Return to top loop level 0.

Type :b for backtrace or :c <option number> to proceed.
Type :bug-form "<subject>" for a bug report template or :? for other options.

CL-USER 48 : 1 >
```

**Problem**

When you have one Lisp form, you need to make sure that it does not contain unknown packages. So first load the system with the software, which also defines the packages. Then find the symbol `cl-ppcre:split` by name `split` in the package `cl-ppcre`:

```
(progn
  (ql:quickload "cl-ppcre")
  (funcall (find-symbol "SPLIT" "CL-PPCRE") "\\s+" "1 2 3"))
```

Above avoids mentioning the symbol `cl-ppcre:split`. Instead we are looking it up at runtime via `find-symbol`.

Or:

```
(progn
   (ql:quickload "cl-ppcre")
   (eval (read-from-string "(cl-ppcre:split  \"\\\\s+\" \"1 2 3\")")))
```

Or: make it two forms:

```
  (ql:quickload "cl-ppcre")  ; loading the software
                             ;  also creates the package CL-PPCRE
  (cl-ppcre:split "CL-PPCRE") "\\s+" "1 2 3"))
```

Comment: Yes that works, but this is a hack. I shouldn't have to mess with symbols just to call a function of a library. I found that replacing `(ql:quickload "cl-ppcre")` with `(require "cl-ppcre")` also works in this example.

Comment: @whitemist : it's not a hack. It's simply necessary, since one otherwise reads the form without having loaded anything. In Common Lisp one can't intern a symbol in a non-existing package. Symbols are a data structure, so one can construct or find them at runtime and FUNCALL can call the symbol function of a symbol. -- the only real other alternative is to have two different forms. One loads the software first. Then the second form gets read and executed. Thus at read time, the symbol and it's package would already exist.

Comment: I understand what you are pointing me. I do not consider this a solution to the problem of using a library the simplest way possible (making a function call), but at least you're teaching me something about how Common Lisp works.

Comment: I think I understand. In the end we need to load the library, which also create a entry in some symbol table, and then we need to use this package entry in the symbol table to have a reference to the / a symbol of the function we want to call. Those need to happen sequentially. And because something in the library loading happens at run time, we can either have 2 forms evaluated sequentially one after the other, or we can put  2 s-expressions in 1 form. But because their symbols are bounded at the same time, we have to manually delay one to make the binding sequential.

Comment: In an approximate way.

Comment: @WhiteMist the symbol table _is_ the package, and a symbol is an entry in that table. also, `ql:quickload` means "the symbol `quickload` in the package `ql`", in case you didn't know.

Comment: @whitemist: the problem is not the binding, the problem is that the package (the namespace) only exists after loading the software (because it contains the necessary package declaration, which generates the package), so the symbol `my-package:my-name` can't be read. Reading means calling the function READ on a stream and returning a symbol. Solutions: A) create the namespace (the package) before reading the problematic form. B) don't include an offending symbol in the form.
---
This is independent of bindings, values, etc. Just reading (-> parsing) the s-expression already fails.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.

You can use `(ql:quickload package)` to install and use. If it's not on your system, it will be downloaded.

Unless you also import the package, you have to prefix the function with the library name.

Can you make this work in your development system?

```
 (ql:quickload :arrow-macros)

 (defun do-it ()
     (arrow-macros:->>
         '(1 2 3 4)
          (mapcar #'1+)
          (reduce #'+)
          ))
```

Comment: Yes it worked fine in the REPL. But it doesn't work on the command line though, I get "Package ARROW-MACROS does not exist."

Comment: OK, I'll bite. Why don't you want to use the REPL??

Comment: One loads systems, not packages. 'package' is in Common Lisp the term for its namespace constructs.

Comment: @FrancisKing I will use the REPL eventually, and very soon. But as my previous workflow with scripting language was entirely done with the terminal and files, I wanted to have this covered. But it is more than that. I didn't precised it at first, but this was not ony a problem with using libraries in one-liners, but also in simple files. Eventually, the programming production are files and scripts, so being able to call libraries from file scripts is not an option, as you know.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I have no idea what the difference is. I'll look it up. Every languages have more or less different manners to manage namespaces, compile time/run time, early/late bindings, etc.. What doesn't help is that each use different words to designate those kind of things. Words are almost emptied of their meaning, they do not contain a values directly, only references to values in an unknown location.

Comment: @WhiteMist a Common Lisp SYSTEM is loadable software: a library or program. A Common Lisp PACKAGE is a namespace for symbols. Common Lisp inherited these names 'system' and 'package' from an earlier Lisp from the 70s.

Comment: @WhiteMist The idea of a development system like Portacle is that you create an image, which you add to interactively. Finally, you dump the image as an executable which you run from a script file. The use of Portacle is highly recommended.

Comment: @Rainer Joswig I thought this would be somthing like this, but it's good to know for sure. I guess nowadays we would call SYSTEM either a library or a compilation unit.

Comment: @FrancisKing Thanks for the recommendation, I will check it out when I'm a little more advanced. But how common is it to produce compiled binaries in Common Lisp ? Is this a cool possibility or is it really the default standard and practical way to produce finished programs ? I'm asking this because I once find a way to produce a compiled binary from an "image" of the state of interpreter (SBCL), and it produced a 30MB binary just for a Hello World.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of how to do this on the quicklisp page itself:
https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/

The example installs quicklisp and eventually uses a library "vecto".